# Testing if something already exists

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to pick up a few more marks for my coursework and my teacher said that this will help. When creating a variable or table etc, I want to know how I can code it so that if it already exists it doesn't run the code.

```
$sql2 = "CREATE TABLE referee(refereeID INT (5) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, name VARCHAR(20))";
if (mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    echo "Table created successfully";
} else {
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}
```

Comment: If we do it all for you, do we get the extra marks or are you going to get them

Comment: `create table if not exists referee ...` - RTM

Comment: your variable is **$sql2** and you are passing **$sql**

Comment: @RiggsFolly loool

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try with this query

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `referee` (
       `refereeID` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
       `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
        PRIMARY KEY  (`refereeID`)
       )";
```

This checks to see if any table like this is in the database.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This example sql statement may help you to undersand how to do it

```
IF  NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects 
WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[YourTable]') AND type in (N'U'))

BEGIN
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[YourTable](
    ....
    ....
    ....
) 

END
```